# IPFS-JS with "npx create-react-app" causes a Webpack Error

Tags: reactjs, webpack, ipfs, js-ipfs

So I created a new React Project with

```
npx create-react-app
```

I added

```
yarn add ipfs
```

I added it to the React project

```
...
const createClient = require("ipfs");
function App() {
...
```

And I get the error

```
TypeError: TextDecoder is not a constructor
```

I think this has something to do with Webpack, and possible how it's configured with JEST. Something about it being set for the Browser.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem ("TypeError: TextDecoder is not a constructor), tho it was when trying to use ipfs-client-http. I found the answer - for me anyway - was to go back to ipfs-client-http v33.1.1.

So my suggestion is to take a look at the date ipfs-client-http was at v33.1.1 and uninstall your ipfs and grab ipfs from back then. My problem was solved immediately!

Good luck
Chris